# Density of points under dyadic transformation

Tags: dynamical-systems, chaos-theory

My question concerns the [Bernoulli map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyadic_transformation) (a.k.a. the shift map and as dyadic transformation).

I understand that most numbers $x \in [0,1)$ do not have a periodic orbit under this transformation, and thus, they densely cover the lines $y=2x$ (for $0 \le x<1/2$) and $y=2x-1$ (for $1/2 \le x<1$). I also understand that a uniform measure on $x$ is invariant under this transformation. Yet, my interest is the density of points on the lines. **I would like to know whether the density of points on these lines, if defined at all, is uniform.**

I also read the answer to the third part of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/637151/bernoulli-map-properties), but couldn't deduce any statement about uniformity of the points on these lines. I'm trained as a physicist, and consequently, lack strong mathematical knowledge. So I would be extra grateful if you consider these facts while writing your response. Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by density of points on these lines? Do you mean that the sequence corresponding to the orbit equi-distributes? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equidistributed_sequence

Comment: @Keen-ameteur Yes, that is what I meant. Also, thanks for the wiki page!

Comment: Seemingly, following the link in that wiki page, the answer to my question is a firm yes due to [equidistribution theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equidistribution_theorem).

Comment: It seems like you are asking about $2^n x \{ mod 1 \}$, while the result you mentioned talks about the sequence $n x\{ mod 1 \}$.

Comment: You're right in that I'm interested in $2^n x \{mod 1\}$. Yet, down in the wiki page it is written that "One noteworthy result is that the sequence $2^ka$ mod 1 is uniformly distributed for almost all, but not all, irrational $a$...", which is my case. Although, I have to correct myself. The answer is not that *firm* and apparently depends on $x$.